# Horizontal swipe in mobile web view using combination of appium and watir

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, appium, watir

I am using  combination of `appium-android` and `watir-cucumber` in our automation  framework.
In mobile emulator i am opening one site in chrome browser.
I want to do horizontal swipe for one of the slider images.

Let me know if anyone know any idea to swipe image from left to right or vice a versa?

I have tried Appium's touch action but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

@Manmohan_singh answer might work but swipe method is **deprecated**... So you should use TouchScreen

***Python code***:

```
screenSize = driver.get_window_size()
screenWidth = screenSize['width']
screenHeight = screenSize['height']   

touchAction = TouchAction(driver)
#Move slider from left to right (finger movement simulation goes from right to left)
touchAction.press(None, screenWidth - (screenWidth/3), y).wait(500).move_to(None, (screenWidth/3), 0).release().perform()
```

Hope it works

Comment: Nope , it doesn't work..  Most of the touch_action does work for mobile apps, whereas it does not work for mobile web view.

Comment: swipe is working fine in mobile app.. like Appium::TouchAction.new.swipe(start_x: 0.5, start_y: 0.2, end_x: 0.5, end_y: 0.8, duration:600).perform  works well in one of the app, but giving problem in mobile web view

Comment: I am using it for both, mobile apps and mobile web view apps... How is exactly your line? What x,y, end_x, end_y, duration are you using?
And what is your Appium version?

Comment: appium version is 1.2.7....... start x, y co-ordinates  (Starting point from where we need to swipe) which i got from uiautomatiorviewer  .... and end x,y are the end point .

Comment: First, could you please update your appium? I am working for example with v1.7.0 (and is not the latest one)
And second, just for you to know. TouchAction coordinates are relative, so end_x and end_y don't represent coordinates from UIAutomatorViewer...  So if you want to move 200 to the right from start_x, end_x will be 200 (your limit is the screen size). If you want to move horizontally your end_y will be 0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for https://github.com/Ricardonacif/touch_action
Touch action is what you should use for swiping

Comment: I have tried it but it shows error   "NoMethodError: undefined method `touch_action' for #<Watir::Div:0x526a5e0>"

Comment: Post exact code to your question that doesn't work for you. It will help understand the problem

Comment: element =page.slide_display_element
element returns element of that slider image                                                            
then i performed touch action on that,
element.touch_action(:swipe,distance: -100)   (this is for left move)
element.touch_action(:flick,axis: 'y', distance:100,duration:50)  (Move downward)